# Most likely number of people to be ill in parish of $n$ people

Tags: calculus, probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Here's a question from my probability textbook:

> If the chance of any given person being ill at any given time is $\theta$, what is the most likely number of persons to be ill at once in a parish of population $n$?

Let's find the most likely number of persons to be ill at once in a parish of population $n$. We want to find the largest integer value of $x$ such that$${ 
  { {{n!}\over{(n-x)!x!}} \theta^x(1- \theta)^{n-x} }\over{  {{n!}\over{(n-x+1)!(x-1)!}} \theta^{x-1}(1- \theta)^{n-x+1}    }} > 1.$$This becomes$${{n-x+1}\over{x}}\left({\theta\over{1 - \theta}} \right) > 1,$$which simplifies to $x < \theta(n+1)$, so the most likely number of persons to be ill at once in such a parish is $\left \lfloor{\theta(n+1)}\right \rfloor$.

However, the answer in the back of my book is $x = \theta n$. So who's correct? If I'm wrong, then where did I specifically go wrong, and how can I modify my answer to get the correct result?

Comment: You rounded to a whole number of humans, which makes sense. Your book prefers fractional humans.

Comment: Your book is wrong, and is being sloppy. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Mode) agrees with you.

Comment: It looks like your book took most likely to be the expected value.

Comment: yes the book answer is wrong and your answer is correct but just a side note, there is also a possibility of two modes if $(n+1) \theta$ is an integer. Right now you are going on the graph from one side but if you come from the other side, you get a lower bound too.